# Import js file in TypeScript without bundling it with Rollup

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, rollupjs

I have a simple TypeScript + Rollup configuration, see [minimal working example here](https://github.com/sonovice/mwe-ts-verovio-import).

The folder structure is as follow:

```
src/mwe.ts
vendor/verovio.js    <-- library, that I would like to use
vendor/verovio.d.ts  <-- content (for now): declare module 'verovio'
```

Now I am trying to use `verovio.js` inside my `mwe.ts`:

```
import * as verovio from '../vendor/verovio.js'

export default class DummyClass {
  constructor() {
    let foo: any = new verovio.toolkit()
  }
}
```

My goal is to have the js library simply copied into the `dist` folder instead of bundled into my own library when executing the js compiler and Rollup. I simply don't unterstand how to do it. The problem here consists of two things, as far as I can see:

1. The type definition is not processed correctly: `error TS2306: File '[...]/mwe/vendor/verovio.d.ts' is not a module.`
2. Rollup does not know how to handle the js file properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a file as a module. Rather than specifying the JS file directly you should make the .d.ts file known to the compiler (e.g. via tsconfig.json or directly via import) and simply import the module afterwards.

```
import '../vendor/verovio';
import * as verovio from 'verovio';

export default class DummyClass {
  constructor() {
    let foo: any = new verovio.toolkit()
  }
}
```

I sent you a pull request at https://github.com/sonovice/mwe-ts-verovio-import/pull/1 that does this and also updates the typings as per documentation of the vendor library. I also edited the Rollup config to copy the vendor library though this is not ideal since your lib will not require() the vendor lib. It would be better to specify this as a dependency and let the module loader take care of the require().

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive help!